# Symfony 3.1.3: Form submit button becomes unresponsive (not disabled) after isValid() errors are triggered and rendered

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have created a form to invite new users. The form has no problem submitting and being handled correctly, until isValid() method returns errors after a submission. When this happens, the page is re-rendered correctly with the appropriate errors being shown. Unfortunately, the submit button then becomes un-responsive: It is still styled correctly (the style changes when it is disabled via jQuery, so that doesn't seem to be the problem), the correct submission URL still appears at the bottom-left of the navigator, but nothing happens when it is clicked.

The UserInviteType form building class:

```
class UserInviteType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('userBackground', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                'Professeur' => 'professor',
                'Étudiant' => 'student',
                'Employé de laboratoire' => 'labEmployee',
                'Employé administratif' => 'adminEmployee',
                'Autre' => 'other'
                )))
            ->add('firstName',  TextType::class)
            ->add('lastName',   TextType::class)
            ->add('email',      EmailType::class)
            ->add('misc',       TextType::class, array( 
                'required' => false,
                ))
            ->add('level',      EntityType::class, array( 
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'AspProfessorProfileBundle:Level',
                'choice_label' => 'value',
                'multiple' => false,
                ))
            ->add('canModify',                      CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type'                    =>  CanModifyInitType::class,
                'allow_add'                     =>  true,
                'allow_delete'                  =>  true,
                'prototype'                     =>  true,
                'required'                      =>  true,
                ))
            ->add('save',   SubmitType::class, array(
                'disabled' => 'false',
                ))

        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Asp\UserBundle\Entity\UserInvite',
            'validation_groups' => array(
                'Asp\UserBundle\Entity\UserInvite',
                'determineValidationGroups'
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

The controller which handles page rendering and form submission:

```
public function usersAction(Request $request)
{

    $user = new UserInvite(); 
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(UserInviteType::class, $user);

    /* retreive all users - for user list rendering*/
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $users = $userManager->findUsers();

    if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
        $data = $form->getData();

        if ($data->getUserBackground() == 'professor' || $data->getUserBackground() == 'adminEmployee' || $data->getUserBackground() == 'other') {
            $canMod = $user->getCanModify();
            foreach ($canMod as $cM) { 
                $user->removeCanModify($cM);     
            }               
        }

        $em->persist($user); 
        $em->flush(); 
        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Invitation envoyé à '.$user->getFirstName().' '.$user->getLastName().'('.$user->getEmail().').'); 

        return $this->redirectToRoute('asp_core_admin_users');
    }

    return $this->render('AspCoreBundle:Admin:users.html.twig', array(
        'users' => $users, 
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

The Twig view rendering of the form:

```
<div class="user-init-form-container">
        {{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }} 
        {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {# ....... Declare other form elements ....... #}

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-9">
                {{ form_widget(form.save, { 'id': 'submit_button', 'label': 'Inviter', 'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        {{ form_end(form) }}

</div>
```

I do not do any jQuery interaction with the submit button directly (except when I wanted to see the disabled button styling to confirm this wasn't the problem).

I have looked around quite a bit and can't seem to find any topic anywhere discussing this. Hope one of you can spot what I am doing wrong, because I am really stumped right now!

Thank you.

Alex S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out.

It was due to a hidden field which was in-properly rendered after error generation. This hidden field suddenly became required and would prevent the submission of the form.

Thank you.

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify form action ?

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'myId'}, 'action':  path('my_route')}) }}
```

Other methods if you prefer http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/action_method.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Thomas. The action seemed to be already mapped correctly, as the correct URL shows at the bottom-left of the navigator. I did try specifying it though, and unfortunately it does not solve the problem. Edit: I tried specifying the method also                 {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('asp_core_admin_users'), 'method': 'POST', 'attr': {'class': 'form-horizontal'}}) }}